# mysql order by doesn't work with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use group by ordering converted back to without ordering joined table:

```sql
select * from (select 
  sf.full_path, sf.folder_name, sf.server_id, p.folder_id, p.user_id, p.permission, u.username, p.id as perm_id
from shared_folders as sf  
inner join permissions as p on (p.folder_id = sf.id)  
inner join users as u on (u.id = p.user_id)  
where sf.server_id = 1 and u.username like "%srkgn%" 
order by p.id desc
) as a
group by folder_id, user_id
```

Comment: The order by in the sub query is not respected in the main query (therefore pointless) - you need to order by in the main query.Also there is no aggregation going on here so the group by will cause non determinate values to be returned

Comment: The `order by p.id desc` in the inner query is useless.

Comment: but I have dublicate records with that query and i need to take last one from dublicate records when use ordering in the main query with group by I always take first dublicate one but I need last one instead

Comment: ' I always take first dublicate one but I need last one instead ' - That's the non determinate nature of the group by (and it may not always return the first one) . - It would help if you could publish sample data,

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` just doesn't make much sense.  The `SELECT` is selecting unaggregated columns that are not aggregation keys; these extra columns should be arguments to aggregation functions.

If you want to select the last record, then the best way is `ROW_NUMBER()`.  But if your query works at all, I'm guessing that you are using an older version of MySQL.

So, use variables.  It is a little cumbersome, but at least accurate:

```
from (select a.*,
             (@rn := if(@fu = concat_ws(':', folder_id, p.user_id), @rn + 1,
                        if(@fu := concat_ws(':', folder_id, p.user_id), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select sf.full_path, sf.folder_name, sf.server_id, p.folder_id, p.user_id, p.permission, u.username, p.id as perm_id
            from shared_folders sf join
                 permissions p
                 on p.folder_id = sf.id join 
                 users u
                 on u.id = p.user_id  
                 where sf.server_id = 1 and
                       u.username like '%srkgn%;
            order by p.folder_id, p.user_id, p.id desc
           ) a cross join
           (select @fu := '', @rn := 0) params
      group by folder_id, user_id
     ) a
where rn = 1;
```